# How to access URL defined with @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat

I want to learn how to program an API in Java/Spring so I downloaded this example on github: https://github.com/bobbrady/spring-rest-drill-bootless.

The app seems to run correctly, however every request I send to /api/user returns an error 404.

For example I'm trying to access the `getUsers()` method, so from what I understand, in `UserApiController` there is an annotation `@RequestMapping("/api/user")`. So I'm guessing that's the base URL, getUsers only specifies a method (get) and no mapping, so I assume I'm supposed to send a GET request to `http://localhost:8080/api/user` with no parameters? But when I do so (in a browser or using Postman), a 404 is returned.

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite no summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: There's a section Usage from the reference above.

Comment: @Roman C Yes even when I follow it I get a 404.

Comment: @GaetanL. The 404 error code is a common for web application. You should figure out a real case.

Comment: @Roman C Is there a way for me to know what URLs have been exposed (is that the correct term?) by the applicatin that is running?

Comment: @GaetanL. No, in Spring you should figure out it yourself from the controller configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded that project and tried to run it with AppMain, and the result was the same as yours. However, if you execute **java -jar target/restdrill.jar** from the command line, it can be accessed correctly. You can try it out.

Comment: And ifyou try to access curl http://localhost:8080/api/user/1, what do you get? Cause I get a 404.

Answer (score 0):

I check the GitHub link that you post, the `/api/user` is defind in `UserAPIController`, you can comprehend it with all api prefix.

The method of `getUsers` that only defind the type to be `RequestMethod.GET`,
consider to change to like this:

```java
@RequestMapping(value= "getUsers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers() {
    System.out.println("Fetching all Users");
    return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(userRepo.getUsers(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

or like this:

```java
@GetMapping("getUsers")
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers() {
    System.out.println("Fetching all Users");
    return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(userRepo.getUsers(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

then you can request to `/api/user/getUsers`

Comment: Why? If I leave the code as is, shouldn't I be able to reach http://localhost:8080/api/user/ ? Because all I get is 404s

Comment: I tried your two methods, and I still get a 404 when calling /api/user/getUsers